# Read deleted object from first cache after deletion in NHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

**Update**

I want to find out whether or not an instance has been deleted from NHibernate's first cache

```
private static void Evict()
        {
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var customers = session.Query<Customer>().ToList();

                var customer = customers[0];
                session.Delete(customer);
                transaction.Commit();

              //how to find out whether or not customers[0] is still in session.
            }

        }
```

Comment: What should this be used for?

Comment: What do you actually want to test?

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense. You are setting a **copy** of the customer to the variable when you say var customer = customers[0];
you are deleting it after the variable is set. The statement:

```
Console.WriteLine(customers[0].CustomerName);
```

is not using the cache - it is using the variable value.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You are trying to test nhibernate works? Really? Fire up a new transaction and query and see what result you get for session.Query<Customer>().Where(x=>x.Id==customerId).Single();

Answer (score 0):

You could try "hacking" the session implementation:

```
var sessionImpl = (ISessionImplementor)session;
var sessionContext = sessionImpl.PersistenceContext;  
var entry = sessionContext.GetEntry(customer);
if (entry.Status == Status.Deleted)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Customer {0} is deleted", customer.Name);
}
```

To be honest: I didn't do this myself, but as far as I can see it should work well. Don't mess around with the session implementation and the context, you can break everything if writing to this classes.

Another more complex but also less "hacky" approach is to register a delete handler. The problem is that a) it is executed when the entity is deleted in the database (say: when the session is flushed) and b) it needs to be registered at configuration time of the session factory, which makes implementation hard.